# htaccess: Custom redirect from any folder to home

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have site with these files and foldes:

```
/index.php ( that include php files contained in folder1 and folder2 )
/config.php
/folder1/
/folder2/
```

I want this:

when a user point to any folder ( folder1, folder2 or any other folder ) then he is redirected to index.php

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/rewriteguide.html). For example, to forward any request to any alphanumerically-named folder to `index.php`, passing the name of the folder as the `GET` parameter `folder`, use something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?folder=$1
```